# How do l make a function that validates and image

Tags: php

l have used the function below but its allowing even pdf to be uploaded
and its not checking if its an image

```
function image_allowed($file_extn) {

        $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');

        $file_name =  $_FILES['image']['image_name'];

        $file_extn =  strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));

        $file_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];



if (in_array($allowed,$file_extn )=== true){
return true;



}else {
return false;


}
```

and l checked using the code below and l dont know were lam getting it wrong

```
if (image_allowed($_POST['image'])=== true) {
 $errors[] = ' images only are allowed.';
```

and l would love to know any checks that l might have ommited here

Comment: You dont need use `===` if you already returning `true` inside your function, just use `if (image_allowed($_POST['image'])) `

Answer (score 2):

While comparing extensions might do the trick, it's not very safe as it easy to fake an extension. I would advise to check the mime types of the files.

**Option 1 - using [`finfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)**

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$file_type = finfo_file($finfo, "image.gif");
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Output for this case: `image/gif`

Just remember to change your `$allowed` array accordingly.
You can see a list of possible mime types for images at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_image).

**Option 2 - Using [`exif-imagetype`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)**

```
exif_imagetype('image.gif')
```

Just notice that in that case your `$allowed` array should contain constants that represent possible return values. (For further information look at the manual - link above)

Answer (score 0):

You can check your image type using pathinfo (http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/your/image/path/');

echo $path_parts['extension']; // Your extension...
```

In your function code:

```
function image_allowed($imagePath) {
    $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');

    $myExtension = pathinfo($imagePath);

    if(in_array($myExtension['extension'], $allowed)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: but the one above lam able to link it with my code how do l improve it

Comment: @PaulKumbweya updated! You just have to pass your image path now

Comment: [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php), Returns information about a file path...

Comment: how do l write it on my case

Comment: Exactly like in that example, what you have to do is just pass the path of your image file. Like `image_allowed('/var/www/myproject/images/image.png')` ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this:

```
function image_allowed() {
    $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
    $file_name =  $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_extn =  strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
    $file_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if (in_array($file_extn,$allowed)=== true){
        return true;
    }

     return false;
}

if (image_allowed()=== false) {
    $errors[] = ' images only are allowed.';
}else{
    //save image or something else
}
```

Comment: make it sure if $_FILES['image']['image_name'] contains uploaded file name

Comment: l have another field called name thts why lam using image_name

Comment: but it is standart fields names for uploaded files
array (size=5)
      'name' => ''
      'type' => ''
      'tmp_name' => ''
      'error' => ''
      'size' => ''

Comment: maybe you mean
$_FILES['image_name']['name'];  <input type="file" name="image_name" />